# is there a way to use a gas stove to supply hot water needs?

Tags: water, heating, gas

We've  a 8kw gas stove which heats huge hallway very well. Wondering is there a way to use it to also heat our water needs (hot water tank very nearby). I'm not a diy type but jus trying to avoid buying a gas boiler just for water? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the US, hot water is often generated by the furnace. These specially designed units have a dedicated coil in the firebox that allows cold water in one end, circulates it through the coil and expels hot water from the other. The benefit (as you suggest) is the use of just one device for both room and water heating. The disadvantage is the main furnace is kept active, even in warm weather, to ensure ongoing access to hot water, a slightly less efficient system.

In theory, you could create a copper coil to run water through a heated area of your stove.  However, this presents numerous complex problems of temperature, routing, sealing, all of which are beyond the skill of most dedicated DIYers. The risks are gas leaks, fire, explosion, water leaks, flood, and a plague of locusts.

**Don't try it!**

Comment: +1 for "all of which are beyond the skill of most dedicated DIYers"

Comment: While everyone is entitled to an anonymous downvote, I am curious to know more about the dissenting view.

Comment: Ok, so if our stove had a "back boiler" we could do this.. (but it doesn't... so we wont be!). If we'd know about (or thought of this) when first putting in the stove .. but not now. Thanks for your informative anwser